# Dynamically Added Image to WrapPanel in WPF

Tags: wpf, dynamic, wrappanel

Added Image Controls to WPF WrapPanel from a list of images defined in xml.
Everything seems to be in place. I even inspected in debug but nothing is visual.
Is there a step I am missing?

```
        _printImages.ReadXml(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Images.xml"));

        if (_printImages.Tables.Contains("image") && _printImages.Tables["image"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (DataRow row in _printImages.Tables["image"].Rows)
            {
                // build info object
                ImageInfo imgInfo = new ImageInfo();

                imgInfo.Source = row["Source"].ToString();
                imgInfo.Custom = bool.Parse(row["Custom"].ToString());
                imgInfo.Font = row["Font"].ToString();
                imgInfo.FontSize = int.Parse(row["FontSize"].ToString());
                imgInfo.CharacterLimit = int.Parse(row["Characterlimit"].ToString());
                imgInfo.CustomType = row["Customtype"].ToString();

                _images.Add(imgInfo);

                //create control
                Image imgControl = new Image();
                BitmapImage imgFile = new BitmapImage();

                try
                {
                    imgFile.BeginInit();
                    imgFile.StreamSource = new FileStream(imgInfo.Source, FileMode.Open);
                    imgControl.Source = imgFile;
                    imgControl.Tag = _images.Count - 1;
                    imgControl.Height = Properties.Settings.Default.ImageHeight;
                    imgControl.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.ImageWidth;
                    imgControl.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(image_MouseDown);
                    imgControl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    imageSelectionPanel.Children.Add(imgControl);
                }

                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Unable to create image");
                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing an `EndInit` call after setting the `StreamSource` property of the BitmapImage.

Moreover, the stream should be closed after loading the bitmap, which is usually done by a `using` block and which also requires to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(imgInfo.Source, FileMode.Open))
{
    imgFile.BeginInit();
    imgFile.StreamSource = stream;
    imgFile.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    imgFile.EndInit();
}
```

Alternatively, the BitmapImages could also be loaded directly from the image file paths without using a FileStream:

```
var imgFile = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgInfo.Source, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

---

You might also create a view model with a collection of ImageInfo objects and bind an ItemsControl to this collection. The ItemsControl would have the WrapPanel as its ItemsPanel, and an ItemTemplate with the Image control:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageInfos}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

See the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx) article on MSDN for details.